# Is there a standard, strided version of memcpy?

Tags: c, memcpy, stride

I have a column vector A which is 10 elements long.  I have a matrix B which is 10 by 10.  The memory storage for B is column major.  I would like to overwrite the first **row** in B with the column vector A.

Clearly, I can do:

```
for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    B[0 + 10 * i] = A[i];
}
```

where I've left the zero in `0 + 10 * i` to highlight that B uses column-major storage (zero is the row-index).

After some shenanigans in CUDA-land tonight, I had a thought that there might be a CPU function to perform a strided memcpy??  I guess at a low-level, performance would depend on the existence of a strided load/store instruction, which I don't recall there being in x86 assembly?

Comment: maybe you should consider switching storage strategy for this matrix, or to store its transpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: The code you have written is as fast as it's going to get.

Long answer: The `memcpy` function is written using some complicated intrinsics or assembly because it operates on memory operands that have arbitrary size and alignment.  If you are overwriting a column of a matrix, then your operands will have natural alignment, and you won't need to resort to the same tricks to get decent speed.

Comment: I guess I just had hopes of assembly level access to say 'un'-strided load/store instructions for dual&triple channel memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'un-strided' load/store operations.

Comment: Perhaps just an incorrect perception on my part, but I thought triple channel ram was striped through the address space?  If I could write to just one of the memory chips (write only in one channel at a slower speed) that would be the equivalent of a strided memcpy? This would of course depend strongly on the granularity of the striping.

Comment: I'm no longer sure what you mean by 'strided memcpy'.  I thought you meant copy from X,X+1,X+2... to Y,Y+N,Y+2*N,...  This has little to do with the way RAM is organized.  I suggest reading about how modern processors work, especially w.r.t. caching.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want: Y, Y+N, Y+2N, ...  Your comment on caching made me realize that it's impractical to transfer to the system bus just to transpose -- sorry, a bit tired here.  Clearly, the code in the question would stay within the L1 cache on my Core i7.

Comment: Its not clear if this is really the case, it is possible to move data faster depending on the alignment of the array. A good memcpy should check the alignment and perform these actions differently if you have the optimal alignment. There is a reasonable chance that the code your compiler emits will not do these checks. There is a bit more to be said about the advantage of using `memcpy`.