# How to copy every N-th byte(s) of a C array

Tags: c++, arrays, wav, sdl-2, fftw

I am writing bit of code in C++ where I want to play a `.wav` file and perform an FFT (with `fftw`) on it as it comes (and eventually display that FFT on screen with `ncurses`). This is mainly just as a "for giggles/to see if I can" project, so I have no restrictions on what I can or can't use aside from wanting to try to keep the result fairly lightweight and cross-platform (I'm doing this on Linux for the moment). I'm also trying to do this "right" and not just hack it together.

I'm using SDL2_audio to achieve the playback, which is working fine. The callback is called at some interval requesting N bytes (seems to be desiredSamples*nChannels). My idea is that at the same time I'm copying the memory from my input buffer to SDL I might as well also copy it in to fftw3's input array to run an FFT on it. Then I can just set `ncurses` to refresh at whatever rate I'd like separate from the audio callback frequency and it'll just pull the most recent data from the output array.

The catch is that the input file is formatted where the channels are packed together. I.E "(LR) (LR) (LR) ...". So while SDL expects this, I need a way to just get one channel to send to FFTW.

The audio callback format from SDL looks like so:

```
void myAudioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len) {
    SDL_memset(stream, 0, sizeof(stream));
    SDL_memcpy(stream, audio_pos, len);
    audio_pos += len;
}
```

where `userdata` is (currently) unused, `stream` is the array that SDL wants filled, and `len` is the length of `stream` (I.E the number of bytes SDL is looking for).

As far as I know there's no way to get `memcpy` to just copy every other sample (read: Copy N bytes, skip M, copy N, etc). My current best idea is a brute-force `for` loop a la...

```
// pseudocode
for (int i=0; i<len/2; i++) {
    fftw_in[i] = audio_pos + 2*i*sizeof(sample)
}
```

or even more brute force by just reading the file a second time and only taking every other byte or something.

Is there another way to go about accomplishing this, or is one of these my best option? It feels kind of kludgey to go from a nice one line memcpy to send to the data to SDL to some sort of weird loop to send it to fftw.

Comment: (I am the same person as OP. Apparently clicking the 'login with GitHub' link didn't lead to the same place as my regular account even though I thought they were the same :P)

Comment: So, your question is basically how to read every other byte from a byte array?

Comment: I don't think the loop is weird at all. It does what you want - stores every other byte from the audio. Memcpy is fast because it is able to storage large blocks of sequential data. You clearly can't do that if you want to skip bytes. Is this causing serious performance issues or are you simply wondering if the code looks good?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013779

Comment: If all that you want to do with the data is compute the fft, then don't even have to copy your data. In fact fftw has support for doing multiple ffts on multiple packed channels. See [here](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html).

Comment: @user2407038 - This is a perfect solution for my goal! It answers the question I meant rather than the one I asked :)

Comment: @h0r53 - No performance issues, nor do I think I'm even close to encountering them. It was more of a "is this the right way to do it" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard OP's solution can be simplified (for copying bytes):

```
// pseudocode
const char* s = audio_pos;
for (int d = 0; s < audio_pos + len; d++, s += 2*sizeof(sample)) {
    fftw_in[d] = *s;
}
```

If I new what `fftw_in` is, I would memcpy blocks `sizeof(*fftw_in)`.

Comment: It turns out that for my specific case `fftw` has built in support for what I'm trying to do, but this is the best answer for the question I actually asked so I'll mark it accepted.

For anyone trying to repeat this with FFTW, see user2407038's answer on the OP

Answer (score 0):

Please check assembly generated by @S.M.'s solution.

If the code is not vectorized, I would use intrinsics (depending on your hardware support) like [_mm_mask_blend_epi8](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_mask_blend_epi8&expand=439,496)

Comment: yes this should be done by SIMD and not normal array accesses